# What's the correct way to use new input types in html5 maintaining fallback for no support?

Tags: html, html-input

The title is pretty explanatory, basically I want to use a new input type in this case "search" while falling back to a type="text" if the browser doesn't support search.

I was guessing it could be like this:

```
<input type="text" type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search posts">
```

But I'm not sure.

How is this usually done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the default behavior, and how HTML5 was designed.  Non-supported types will fall back to `type=text`.

Source:  [Dive into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html)

> As with all the other new input types, browsers that don’t recognize type="search" will treat it like type="text", so there is absolutely no reason not to start using type="search" for all your search boxes today.

**Edit**

As pointed out in the comments, you don't need the two `type` attributes, just `type=search`:

```
<input type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search posts">
```

Comment: Note that this means that the correct HTML is simply `<input type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search posts">`